# Removing spesific non-alphanumeric character from a string

Tags: javascript, regex, api

I want to get rid of these '[]' brackets from a string output. But I couldn't manage to do it. Here is how I tried;

```
.then((data) => (result.innerHTML = data.list[0].definition.replace(/^[]/i , ''))
```

I tried a lot of different variations of this, also tried removing all alphanumeric characters, but it also removes dots, comas and stuff like that. My only issue is random words have brackets like this.
Also my attempts don't even throw an error.

Comment: Escape them: `\[\]`

Comment: Can you show an example string and the desired result?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
.then((data) => (result.innerHTML = data.list[0].definition.replace(/[\][]/g , "");
```